# Extracting recording audio samples while recording

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder, avasset

I'm working on an audio recorder that renders the waveform of each recording.  Whenever a recording is made, the `NSURL` of the audio file is converted to an `AVAsset`.  With the `AVAsset` I'm able to extract the samples of the audio track.  This works fine for audio recordings that are short ( <40seconds), but the process takes 15-20 seconds on a 2.5 min track and only gets worse the longer the track is.  Anyone have any tips or recommendations on how to get around this problem?

```
AVAssetReader *reader = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:self.audioAsset error:&error];

AVAssetReaderTrackOutput *output = [[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput alloc] initWithTrack:songTrack outputSettings:outputSettingsDict];

[reader addOutput:output];

NSMutableData * data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:32768];

NSMutableArray *allSamples = [NSMutableArray array];


while (reader.status == AVAssetReaderStatusReading) {
        CMSampleBufferRef sampleBufferRef = [output copyNextSampleBuffer];

        if (sampleBufferRef) {
            CMBlockBufferRef blockBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(sampleBufferRef);
            size_t bufferLength = CMBlockBufferGetDataLength(blockBufferRef);

            if (data.length < bufferLength) {
                [data setLength:bufferLength];
            }

            CMBlockBufferCopyDataBytes(blockBufferRef, 0, bufferLength, data.mutableBytes);

            Float32 *samples = (Float32 *)data.mutableBytes;
            int sampleCount = (int)(bufferLength / bytesPerInputSample);
            for (int i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++) {
                [allSamples addObject:@(samples[i*channelCount])];
            }
            CMSampleBufferInvalidate(sampleBufferRef);
            CFRelease(sampleBufferRef);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The first place I'd look is `[allSamples addObject...]`. Try commenting that line out and compare the performance.